# How to create a web form using python and flask on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create a web page using python and flask on pythonanywhere.com
The page is very simple. The user will enter a url in the box and click submit, the page then shows the url they submitted.

I am trying to do it on one page. If the method is GET, then display the form and allow the user to submit a url. If the method is POST, then print the url passed in the form.

I tried it multiple ways but it did not work. I can see the form and submit the url, but could never print it or put every thing in one page

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '''
    <form action="process" method="post">
    <p>Enter a URL for a\ web page:</p>
  <input type="text" name="url"></input>
  <input type="submit" value="Process"></input>
</form>'''

@app.route("/process", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def process():
    url = request.form['url']
    print("The url address is '" + url + "'")
```

Comment: You have to use `ajax` to submit your form and get the result and print it in the DOM ,if you want everything in one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print, this would go into your PythonAnywhere webapp logs. Instead, if you want to get that back as a website response, you would have to return it.

(and also reload your webapp after you make any changes)